# Derivative of Jacobi elliptic function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, elliptic-functions

Let $k \in (0,1)$ and $w>0$. Consider the function $\varphi: \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by
$$\varphi(\xi)= \frac{\sqrt{2}k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\cdot \text{sn} \left(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{w}\sqrt{k^2+1}};k\right),\forall \ \xi \in \mathbb{R},$$
where $\text{sn}$ denote the Jacobi elliptic function *snoidal*. I want calculate $\eta:=\frac{d}{dw} \varphi$. How do I proceed? Do I apply the chain rule normally? In doing so, I arrived at
 $$\eta (\xi)= \frac{\sqrt{2} \;k}{\sqrt{k^2+1}} \frac{\xi}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\cdot\left(\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{w^3}}\right)\cdot \frac{d}{d\xi} \text{sn}\left(\frac{\xi}{\sqrt{w}\sqrt{k^2+1}};k\right), \; \forall \; \xi \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Is that correct? If not, how should I proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First:
$$
\frac{d}{dz} \operatorname{sn}(z;k) = \operatorname{cn}(z;k)\operatorname{dn}(z;k).
$$
Then
$$
\frac{d}{dw}\left[{\frac {\sqrt {2}k}{\sqrt {{k}^{2}+1}}{\;\operatorname{sn}} \left( {\frac {
\xi}{\sqrt {w}\sqrt {{k}^{2}+1}}};k \right) }\right]
=\\
-\,{\frac {\sqrt {2}k\xi}{2 \left( {k}^{2}+1 \right) {w}^{3/2}}{\;\operatorname{cn}} \left( {\frac {\xi}{\sqrt {w}\sqrt {{k}^{2}+1}}};k \right) {
\;\operatorname{dn}} \left( {\frac {\xi}{\sqrt {w}\sqrt {{k}^{2}+1}}};k
 \right) }
$$

....

When you write $\frac{d}{d\xi}$ in there, it is confusing.  But in one interpretation, your calculation could be correct.

Comment: Thank's! I believe that we are thinking the same thing. So, do you agree with me that $\eta'(0)=0$?

Comment: Well, when you write $\eta'$ do you mean the derivative with respect to $w$ or $\xi$?  When you write $\eta(\xi)$ you mean the variable is $\xi$?  Strange notation!  I do **not** agree that: take the derivative of $\varphi$ with respect to $w$, then with respect to $\xi$ and then evaluate at $\xi=0$, you get $0$.  I do agree that if you take the derivative of $\varphi$ twice with respect to $w$, then evaluate at $\xi = 0$, you get $0$.